# How to fix a not working Space key in python?

Tags: python, pygame

Can any one see what I did wrong, please? I want the block to jump but it doesnt work properly. This is my first python project so please try to explain what I did wrong so I dont do it again, thanks.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')


class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.Jumpcount = 10
        self.Isjump = False

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width / 2, self.height / 2))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 255, 0), (self.x + self.width / 2, self.y + self.height / 2, self.width / 2, self.height / 2))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (139, 26, 26), (0, 400 + self.height, 500, 500 - self.height))

    def Jump(self, Jumping):
        if Jumping:
            self.Isjump = True
        if self.Isjump:
            if self.Jumpcount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if self.Jumpcount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                self. y = self.Jumpcount**2 * 0.25 * neg
                self.Jumpcount -= 1
            else:
                self.Isjump = False
                self.Jumpcount = 10


win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
Jumping = False
run = True
man = Player(70, 400, 40, 40)
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print('123')
                Jumping = True
                man.Jump(Jumping)

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

There is no error message but when I press space it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `pygame.event.get()` loop. The first loop is consuming all the events, but checks only the `QUIT` event and does nothing for other events. The second loop is likely empty. Do all the event checks in the first loop.
You want to have only one event loop each iteration of the main loop.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            print('123')
            Jumping = True
            man.Jump(Jumping)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in having two for loops `event in pygame.event.get()`
To fix this you just want to have the two if statements under one for loop like so:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print('123')
                Jumping = True
                man.Jump(Jumping)
```

that should fix your problem.